# Needing to move content from postmeta to posts in sql

Tags: sql

I have conent located in a custom field named main_content in wp_postmeta and need to copy that content to post_content in wp_posts. There are about 400 posts and have no sql background but should be pretty easy I think, just not sure on the right code?

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `post_id` IS main_content AND INSERT INTO wp_posts WHERE `post_id` IS `post_content`
```

Something like above but not sure if that is correct

Comment: If you don't know SQL, why not use WP API functions, such as get_posts & get_post_meta - they are safe and the performance of the query does not matter so much, as it is a one off migration?